# How to identify scenarios and steps with numerical ids on cucumber?

Tags: testing, automation, cucumber, bdd, uniqueidentifier

### Looking into a nice approach for identifying scenarios and steps with numerical ids on cucumber

- Don't want to use code line number for this, that can change after editing features.
- I'm already using tags to identify/group scenarios but customer requires a unique number to refer them.
- Ideal solution would take care of this automagically perhaps a cucumber gem with some sort of persistence support.

As of now, i will simply use tags with hard-coded numerical ids on it, e.g.

```
@login @tc10100
Scenario: Login with wrong credentials
  Given I am not logged in
  And I go to the user signin page
  #and so on...
```

Notes about this temporary tagged (@tc10100) solution:

- tc stands for Test Case (customer is accustomed to that term)
- 10100 is just some initial case number
- since a good designed scenario will not include more than 9 steps, step numbers will be counted automatically, starting on step 1, 2, 3... So @tc10100 step 2 is "And I go to the user signin page"

Answer (score 2):

The best solution here may be create scenarios ids based on the scenario's name.

Do you have a any kind of constraints about the id max length ?

If not we can start thinking about some sort of scenario unique hash applying md5 or something like that to the scenario's name.

Comment: Should be easy to read id, like trac ids #321 #232 ... preferably no more that 5 digits long, probably restarted counting after certain amount of sprints are met, or per milestone maybe. thanks ;)

Comment: Now that i think about it, your solution is quite effective, i have to consider the case when someone changes the scenario name to update it or improve its description and that should do it.